# Freecodecamp python time calculator not initiating tests

Tags: python-3.x

I've follow a tutorial writing the code below, however when I run the console just sits idle, if you couldn't tell, I'm new to cod ing, any guidance on where I've gone wrong would be appreciated - also tips welcome.
here is the python code;

```html
def add_time(start, duration, day_of_week=False):

  print(add_time)
  week_days_index = {"monday": 0, "tuesday": 1, "wednesday": 2, "thursday": 3, "friday": 4, "saturday": 5, "sunday": 6}

  week_days_array = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

  duration_tuple = duration.partition(":")
  duration_hours = int(duration_tuple[0])
  print(duration_hours)
  duration_minutes = int(duration_tuple[2])
  print(duration_minutes)

  start_tuple = start.partition(":")
  start_minutes_tuple = start_tuple[2].partition(" ")
  start_hours = int(start_tuple[0])
  start_minutes = int(start_tuple_minutes[0])
  am_pm = start_tuple_minutes[2]
  ampm_flip = {"AM": "PM", "PM": "AM"}

  day_amount = int(duration_hours / 24)

  end_minutes = start_minutes + duration_minutes
  if(end_minutes >= 60):
    start_hours += 1
    end_minutes = end_minutes % 60

  amount_ampmflips = int((start_hours + duration_hours) / 12)
  end_hours = (start_hours + duration_hours) % 12

  end_minutes = end_minutes if end_minutes > 9 else "0" + str(end_minutes)
  end_hours = end_hours = 12 if end_hours == 0 else end_hours
  if (am_pm == "PM" and start_hours + (duration_hours % 12) >= 12):
    day_amount += 1

  am_pm = ampm_flip[am_pm] if amount_ampmflip % 2 == 1 else am_pm

  returntime = str(end_hours) + ":" + str(end_minutes) + " " + am_pm
  if (day_of_week):
    day_of_week = day_of_week.lower()
    index = int((week_days_index[day_of_week]) + day_amount) % 7
    new_day = week_days_array[index]
    returntime += "," + new_day

  if (day_amount == 1):
    return returntime + " " + "(next_day)"
  elif(day_amount > 1):
    return returntime + " (" + str(day_amount) + " days later)"

  return returntime
```

Comment: This can be closed as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and ran into some typos that you might want to correct in case anyone else reviews this issue looking for solutions.  In your code above, you have a variable named "start_minutes_tuple" that is later referred to as "start_tuple_minutes".

Also, there is a variable named "amount_ampmflips" that is later referred to as "amount_ampmflip".  Both of these caused errors when testing.  Also, it took a bit of guessing as to the format of the parameters to enter to make a test call to your function.  You might want to add that in.

With those bits, I did construct a test program that I believe follows the spirit of your project.

```
def add_time(start, duration, day_of_week=False):

  print(add_time)
  week_days_index = {"monday": 0, "tuesday": 1, "wednesday": 2, "thursday": 3, "friday": 4, "saturday": 5, "sunday": 6}

  week_days_array = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

  duration_tuple = duration.partition(":")
  duration_hours = int(duration_tuple[0])
  print(duration_hours)
  duration_minutes = int(duration_tuple[2])
  print(duration_minutes)

  start_tuple = start.partition(":")
  start_tuple_minutes = start_tuple[2].partition(" ")
  start_hours = int(start_tuple[0])
  start_minutes = int(start_tuple_minutes[0])
  am_pm = start_tuple_minutes[2]
  ampm_flip = {"AM": "PM", "PM": "AM"}

  day_amount = int(duration_hours / 24)

  end_minutes = start_minutes + duration_minutes
  if(end_minutes >= 60):
    start_hours += 1
    end_minutes = end_minutes % 60

  amount_ampmflip = int((start_hours + duration_hours) / 12)
  end_hours = (start_hours + duration_hours) % 12

  end_minutes = end_minutes if end_minutes > 9 else "0" + str(end_minutes)
  end_hours = end_hours = 12 if end_hours == 0 else end_hours
  if (am_pm == "PM" and start_hours + (duration_hours % 12) >= 12):
    day_amount += 1

  am_pm = ampm_flip[am_pm] if amount_ampmflip % 2 == 1 else am_pm

  returntime = str(end_hours) + ":" + str(end_minutes) + " " + am_pm
  if (day_of_week):
    day_of_week = day_of_week.lower()
    index = int((week_days_index[day_of_week]) + day_amount) % 7
    new_day = week_days_array[index]
    returntime += "," + new_day

  if (day_amount == 1):
    return returntime + " " + "(next_day)"
  elif(day_amount > 1):
    return returntime + " (" + str(day_amount) + " days later)"

  return returntime

# Added this in to perform a test of the function - it should print out 9:00 PM
  
new_time = add_time("10:00 AM","11:00")
print(new_time)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback! Sorry for not adding a test function in, yeah you definitely followed the spirit, my main issue was somehow messing up the configuration of the run command in my virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

don't worry, got it.
I think it had to done with Replit's configurable run command, I must of mess with it.
Tips still welcome.

Comment: welcome to SO, please make sure your answers are constructive.

Comment: This answer can be deleted, as it does not shed much light on the solution.